# CSS Absolute positioned div overflow inside content

Tags: html, css

I tried to create an active searchbox which will show some result with a description, which works great. But the custom dropdown I created is cut off by the parent DIV at the bottom. As shown in the image, the popup is cut off at the bottom. [Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8po8R.png)

The code for the dropdown is:

```
div.searchResults {
width: 100%;
background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
border: 1px solid rgb(237, 237, 237);
border-top: none;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 900;
```

When I add overflow-y:scroll to the parent I get the following result:
[Image example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BriHe.png)

The problem here is the parent gets a scrollbar which it should not. But this way I get a little example of how it should work.
What I actually want is: [100% Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LHR4.png)

I have tried pretty much everything the last 3 hours, but didn't figure it out. Change the position or box-sizing didn't work, neither did overflow:visible.

Thanks for your help

This is the reduced HTML:

```
<article class="clearfix">
<div class="entry-content clearfix">
    <form asp-action="add" asp-controller="vacancy" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="product-inner">

            <div class="vacancy_save_input_row">
                <p>Requirement</p>
                <div class="picked-requirements">
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="requirement-search">
                    <input id="search_box_requirement" type="text" placeholder="Requirement" @*class="noradiusbottom"*@>
                    <div class="searchResults" style="display:none;">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- .entry-content -->
```

Vacancy_save_input_row has the following CSS:

```
.product-inner > .vacancy_save_input_row {
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

}

Entry-content has:

box-sizing:border-box;

And the product-inner class has:

```
min-height: 94px;
```

Comment: What are the styles for the containing element (the parent element)?

Comment: set max-height to searchResults  element and set overflow:auto

Comment: Can you post the code for the parent container and the child container with their html and CSS?

Comment: I updated the post with the CSS, setting max-height and overflow:auto works. But only if I keep the max-height to around 180px otherwise it will be cut off anyway.